# How can I tell if there are three or more characters between matches in a regex?

Tags: regex, ruby, string

I'm using Ruby 2.1.  I have this logic that looks for consecutive pairs of strings in a bigger string

```
results = line.scan(/\b((\S+?)\b.*?\b(\S+?))\b/)
```

My question is, how do I iterate over the list of results and print out whether there are three or more characters between the two strings?  For instance if my string were

```
"abc      def"
```

The above would produce

```
[["abc      def", "abc", "def"]]
```

and I'd like to know whether there are three or more characters between "abc" and "def."

Comment: You refer to "three or more characters between the two strings" (which is consistent with your regex), but your example contains only spaces (that is, one particular character) between the two strings. That is confusing.

Comment: I was using an example taht matched my expression.  I used the word "characters" instead of "spaces" in my question b/c my regex could potentially match more than spaces.  Please let me know what I can do to make the quesiton clearer.  Thanks Cary.

Comment: @Dave What could there be potentially else than spaces?

Answer (score 3):

Use a quantifier for the spaces inbetween: [`\b((\S+?)\b\s{3,}\b(\S+?))\b`](https://regex101.com/r/v3oG9M/1)

Also, the inner boundries are not really needed:
[`\b((\S+?)\s{3,}(\S+?))\b`](https://regex101.com/r/v3oG9M/2)

Comment: Your changing my regex though.  I don't want to exclude pairs that have less than 3 characters between them, I just want to identify which ones those are when i iterate over my result set.

Comment: Dave, it is not necessary to reference your "result set" to produce the result you desire.  wp78de is extracting strings with 3 or more spaces between the two matches (which would be in your result set), consistent with your example. If it should be "3 or more *characters*" between matches, replace `\s{3,}` with `.{3,}`.

Comment: @Dave if you really would like to go that route you could use a more complex pattern like this that has value in $2 if there are 3 or more spaces in between: [´\b(?:(\w+?)(?:(\s{3,})|\b.*?\b)(\w+?))\b´](https://regex101.com/r/v3oG9M/3)

Answer (score -1):

A straightforward way to check this is by running a separate regex:

```
results.select!{|x|p x[/\S+?\b(.*?)\b\S+?/,1].size}
```

will print the size for every of the bunch.

Another way is to take the size of the captured groups and subtract them:

```
results = []
line.scan(/\b((\S+?)\b.*?\b(\S+?))\b/) do |s, group1, group2|
    results << $~ if s.size - group1.size - group2.size >= 3
end
```